# Retrieve value from img tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the `favoriteid` value.

```
<td class="favoriteRow" style="">

  <img src="/images/starGold.png" loading="lazy" favoriteid="bitcoin">

</td>
```

This is what I tried but got back `undefined`.

```
console.log(this.childNodes[0]['favoriteid'])
```

The console.log(this) outputs:

```
<td class="favoriteRow" style="">

  <img src="/images/starGold.png" loading="lazy" favoriteid="bitcoin">

</td>
```

Comment: It’s very strange that you figured to log `this` and `this.childNodes[0].favoriteid` but never logged `this.childNodes` or `this.childNodes[0]` to see what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)!

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img[favoriteid]");
console.log( img.getAttribute("favoriteid") )
```

```html
<td class="favoriteRow" style="">
  <img src="/images/starGold.png" loading="lazy" favoriteid="bitcoin">
</td>
```

or

```
document.querySelector(".favoriteRow img").getAttribute("favoriteid")
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".favoriteRow img").getAttribute("favoriteid"));
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="favoriteRow" style="">
    <img src="/images/starGold.png" loading="lazy" favoriteid="bitcoin">
  </td>
</table>
```